# Django: If user has entered address previously

Tags: django, django-templates, django-forms, django-views

I want to present a user with a form if he has not filled it out previously on login but redirect him to the homepage if he has filled in information previously. 
How do i accomplish this?

Here's my view:

```
def makinginfo(request):
    form = SongForm(request.POST or None)
    songprofile =  SongProfile.objects.get().filter(user=request.user)
    if songprofile = null: IS THIS RIGHT?     
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            sp = SongProfile
            sp.song = form.pk
            sp.save()
            if 'next' in request.POST:
               next = request.POST['next']
            else:
               next = reverse('index_show')
               return HttpResponseRedirect(next)
        return render_to_response(
        'song/create.html',
           {'form':form},

             context_instance = RequestContext(request)
               )

     else:
        return render_to_response(
        'song/show.html',
         context_instance = RequestContext(request)
               )
```

Am i on the right track here?

Thanks,

ADDITIONAL INFO:

SongProfile and Song are two different models. SongProfile model is as follows: 
`class SongProfile(models.Model): 
    song = models.OneToOneField(Song)` 
so when im trying to save both in song and songprofile where songprofile.song saves the latest id/pk of the record created in song. is this wrong?

Comment: 1) You don't need the `.get()`. Make it just `SongProfile.objects.filter(user=request.user)` 2) `null` does not exist in Python. The equivalent is `None`, but all you have to do is check `if songprofile:` 3) Generally speaking, One-to-one relationships are only worthwhile if you need to add info to a model you don't control. If you control both, the fields on `SongProfile` should just go on `Song`. 4) You're missing the data dictionary parameter on the last `render_to_response`, pass an empty dict (`{}`) if you don't need anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming there is only one SongProfile object per user.

```
 try:
    songprofile = SongProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    # Render song/show.html
 except SongProfile.DoesNotExist:
   if form.is_valid():
      # Process post

   # Render song/create.html
```

To create a new SongProfile object with the Song created by the form:

```
 song = form.save()
 songprofile = SongProfile(user=request.user)
 songprofile.song = song
 songprofile.save()
```

---

**EDIT AGAIN**:

Fixed backwards stuff and added Song object.

Comment: @Natim  That is the syntactically correct version of `songprofile = null`, yes, but when using `get()`, a nonexistent result raises an exception--not returns null.

Comment: Yes I know your answer it the good one :) I just told him since he asked if it was correct.

Comment: SongProfile and Song are two different models. SongProfile model is as follows: `class SongProfile(models.Model):
    song = models.OneToOneField(Song)` so when im trying to save both in song and songprofile where songprofile.song saves the latest id/pk of the record created in song. is this wrong?

Comment: also shouldn't they be the other way round... songprofile.doesnotexist should render the form and process the post?

Answer (score 2):

You can, indeed, do a `try/catch` as Tim demonstrated and that will work. If you find that you are, in some cases, beginning to filter more fields or that you want a sensible default, you can do as the docs suggest and use the `get_or_create()` method, like so:

```
sp, created = SongProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)
```

From the [docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create):

> Any keyword arguments passed to get_or_create() -- except an optional one called defaults -- will be used in a get() call. If an object is found, get_or_create() returns a tuple of that object and False. If an object is not found, get_or_create() will instantiate and save a new object, returning a tuple of the new object and True.

So the Boolean value indicates if the object needed to be created or not and you can use it to guide method logic.

This syntax, too, is a little briefer and cleaner.

As far as trying to save both `Song` and `SongProfile`, no, you're not wrong. As Tim demonstrated, `form.save()` creates the new `song` and `songprofile.song = song`, followed by the `songprofile.save()`, saves the `songprofile`'s song reference.

There are a couple of small errors in the code example. One error is,

```
if songprofile = null:
    ...
```

which, were you to use it, as @Natim noted, should be,

```
if songprofile is None:
    ...
```

Another problem is in the line,

```
sp = SongProfile
```

which Python will, indeed, compile, but which assigns the `SongProfile` class object reference to the variable and not an instance of the class itself. What you want to do normally would be,

```
sp2 = SongProfile()
```

and that will create the object instance. If you do a `dir(sp)` and `dir(sp2)`, you'll see the difference.